# Navbar styling active underline

Tags: css, reactjs, navbar, nav

I have a nav bar that animates an underline when the user hover overs the link. I am trying to add css so the active nav bar has a permanent underline.

My code

```
<Navbar className="navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm" light>
                <Container id="ContainerGrnH">
            <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNavbar} className="mr-2" />
                    <Collapse className="d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse" isOpen={!this.state.collapsed} navbar>
            <div class="topnav">
              <ul className="navbar-nav flex-grow">
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-white"  to="/home">HOME <div className="underline"></div></NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                    <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-white" to="/people-profiles">PEOPLE PROFILES<div className="underline"></div></NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                    <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-white" to="/Role-types">ROLE TYPES<div className="underline"></div></NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                    <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-white" to="/support">SUPPORT<div className="underline"></div></NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                    <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-white" id="contactushead" to="/contact-us">CONTACT US<div className="underline"></div></NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </Collapse>
          </Container>
            </Navbar>
```

```
.topnav ul a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}
.topnav ul li .underline {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 0%;
    transition: width 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.topnav ul li.active-link .underline {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

.topnav ul li:hover .underline {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

.topnav ul li:hover a {
}

.topnav ul li:active a {
    transition: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.76);
}

.topnav ul li:active .underline {
    transition: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.76);
}
```

It's most likely a slight error but I've been playing around for a bit now and can't seem to find many solutions.

[image]

As you can see by the image the word home should be underlined as home has been selected.

Comment: Can you please make some editable code in codesendbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using react-router-dom's NavLink?

If so, there is actually an activeClassName props which could be use to identify the route is currently being visited.

```
<NavLink tag={Link} className="text-white" exact activeClassName="underline" to="/people-profiles">PEOPLE PROFILES</NavLink>
```

and in your css

```
.underline {
 border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

Don't forget to add **exact** in the NavLink's props to match properly with the route.

read more here:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md

Comment: added this but can't seem to get working ill keep playing around with it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add `activeClassName="underline"` to your `NavLink`. And know that you're not underlying in your CSS. checkout how to do it in @crmacarse answer.